# how to use jquery with array of information coming from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a way to properly read an array coming from a php script:

php:

```
$query="SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIME) as epoch_time FROM node WHERE netid='$netid'";
$result=mysql_query($query, $conn);

// Plot our nodes
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{

    $longitude=$row["longitude"];
    $latitude=$row["latitude"];

    $points[] = array('lat' => $latitude, 'lng' => $longitude);


}

mysql_close($conn);
print_r ($points);
```

the result of script when called in standalone:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [lat] => 35.91204361476439 [lng] => 39.05123084783554 ) [1] => Array ( [lat] => 36.91204361476439 [lng] => 38.05123084783554 ) [2] => Array ( [lat] => 33.33 [lng] => 34.44 ) [3] => Array ( [lat] => 35.78 [lng] => 33.2 ) [4] => Array ( [lat] => 37.000000 [lng] => 32.3456 ) )
```

Now I want to manage by ajax this array, getting the pair of latitude and longitude for each element in the array  I have the following idea:

```
function loadPoints(){

    $.ajax({
        url:'markers.php',
        success:function(points){
        var markers = {};
        markers = points;
        for (var i in markers) {
        $.each(markers[i], function(key, val){
        var position = [val.lat, val.lng];
        console.log(position);
        });
        }
       }
    });
```

but it is not working. Any idea How can I manage this array?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) in you PHP (instead of print_r).

and you can use [$.getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
$.getJSON( 'markers.php', function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        var position = [val.lat, val.lng];
        console.log(position);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you it worked like a charm and seems faster then previous solution

Answer (score 1):

`print_r` is designed for outputting data for debugging purposes. It isn't a standard data format, and jQuery has no special rules for handling it (especially if you tell it that you are sending it HTML).

So:

1. Tell the client that you are sending JSON: `header("Content-Type: application/json");`
2. Output JSON: `print json_encode($points);`

Then:

```
success:function(points){
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var marker = points[i];
        // etc
```

Note that I removed:

```
var markers = {};
markers = points;
```

since creating an empty object, then immediately overwriting it is pointless. Just use the variable you already have.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the script called in standalone is exactly what jQuery will be reading. So `var points = 'Array ( [0] => Array ( [lat] => 35.91204361476439 [lng] => 39.05123084783554 ) [1] => Array ( [lat] => 36.91204361476439 [lng] => 38.05123084783554 ) [2] => Array ( [lat] => 33.33 [lng] => 34.44 ) [3] => Array ( [lat] => 35.78 [lng] => 33.2 ) [4] => Array ( [lat] => 37.000000 [lng] => 32.3456 ) )`.  This is a prime example of when to use [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

In `markers.php`, change `print_r($points);` to `echo json_encode($points);`.  And then modify your jQuery slightly to expect a JSON object as a response:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'markers.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(points) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace [print_r](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) with [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).  json_encode will encode the php array as JSON.

```
echo json_encode( $points );
```